# How to make a timer that makes a page go live at a specific time?

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

We'd like to hide our content until it's midnight on a certain day; after that time, we'd like to show an iframe to a certain form. How can this be achieved? I was wondering if maybe you'd use the jQuery countdown plugin in combination with something?

Comment: A client side solution will not really hide the content - it would be visible to anyone with a bit of technical skill. You want to do this on server side if you want to do it properly.

Comment: SO is for specific questions relating to software problems, not a place for providing free code solutions. Please post what you've already tried, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: You'd better do this serverside, because the user can manipulate it's local time or your countdowntimer easily.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will definitely look into doing this server side. As for BenM, I understand, but you're post is not helpful at all, please keep your post relevant and helpful; I did not want a free code solution, just a tip and/or next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only proper solution is to do the check serverside, because anything with timers can be manipulated on clientside with (relative) ease.

It should be something like the following (pseudocode):

serverside script:

```
// normal stuff

if (servertime == your desired time){
      // include the special codez
      // It's probably best to have that iframe content in a separate file
      // and just import the file here
}

// more normal stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, that has given me a great starting point.

Comment: @beta208 you are welcome. It's best you accept this answer to mark your issue as solved for now, and ask another question if you run into trouble later. Don't forget to include some code, normally this will attract more people to upvote and answer your question as it shows your research efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Doing clientside doesn't hide much from user...

But This is a very basic algo am writing here of client side..u can use `settimeout()' of javascript...

```
function TestTime(reqTime) {
 var date=new Date();
 if(date.getHours()===reqTime.getHours() && date.getMinutes()===reqTime.getMinutes()) { // you may need to add other validations like date etc
   //on success either redirect to other page or show the hidden content 
   location.href=""//the redirected page may need to validate on server side
   $('div').show() // show content
} else {
  $('div').html('Some content'); //you can show counter kind of thing here
  window.setTimeout(TestTime, 1000, true);


}
}
```